# How to create a Word paragraphformat object form an Excel macro

Tags: excel, vba, object, ms-word

I create a new Word document form an Excel macro and that works fine.
Now I want to create a new ParagraphFormat object to apply to a lot of paragraphs.
Microsoft Office Dev Center gives an example for a macro in word.

```
Set oWord_app = CreateObject("Word.Application")
oWord_app.Documents.Add
Set oDoc = oWord_app.Documents(1)

'Micorsoft Def Center:
Dim myParaF As New ParagraphFormat 
myParaF.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter 
myParaF.Borders.Enable = True 
ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(1).Format = myParaF
```

To adapt this Word macro to my Excel macro I think I have to write

```
Dim myParaF as new oWord_app.ParagraphFormat
```

but that failed. What’s the right way?

Comment: Have you added a reference to Word in your VBProject ?  If you have not then you cannot define variables as types from the Word library, nor can you use Word constants like `wdAlignParagraphCenter`

Comment: *How* did "it fail"? Did you get an error? What was it? FWIW leave out the `New` keyword - this won't work with the Office object models except for instantiating an instance of an application.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your advice. I’m sorry, but I really did not think to check the references.
I had only a reference to Microsoft Office 14.0 Object library, now I also a reference to Microsoft Word 14.0 Object Library. And now it works. The new statement is apparently necessary, otherwise I get the error “variable not known”. 
I still wonder why it works only without “Word_app. ParagraphFormat” , but already with “ParagraphFormat”.
Thank you very much.

here my code in shot words:

```
    Option Explicit
    Dim Word_app As Object, oDoc As Object, bWordVorhanden As Boolean, pFormat As Object

Sub DocumentCreate()

    Set Word_app = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Word_app.Visible = True
    Word_app.Documents.Add
    Set oDoc = Word_app.Documents(1)

Set pFormat = New ParagraphFormat 
pFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
pFormat.Borders.Enable = True
ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(1).Format = pFormat

    With oDoc.Paragraphs(1).Range
        .Font.Name = "Arial"
        .Font.Size = 11
        .Font.Bold = True
        .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = 1 'wdAlignParagraphCenter
        .InsertAfter "hello" 'Text:=Str(oDoc.Paragraphs.Count)
        .ParagraphFormat.SpaceBefore = 12
        .ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 6
    End With

End Sub
```